# libpq : get binary date

Tags: date, libpq

Im using libpq and I'm getting the data in binary format. 
I correctly received timestamp data and basic formats (float, int, long and such).

But, I'm not able to understand DATEOID format, and I was not able to find any clue in the documentation.

Hoy do I work with the data I get using PQgetvalue ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like is a 32 bit integer holding the days elapsed since 2000-01-01.